# Google Sheets: Transpose with Arrayformula skipping first row

Tags: google-sheets

I am wondering why the following formula skips the first row:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)=1;"Bestellte Gesamtmenge";transpose(arrayformula(BestelltabelleImport!I11:IS11))))
```

Here is an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vltrf6686hsER3B9g4Kwsm2Hk7kz73aD9yG9BX3QPB8/edit#gid=1278617356

Look at the tab "Complete" which shows row 1 with "320" and "Eier".

However, the tab "Missing first row" which applies above formula does not show this row of results.

The only difference between the formulas on those two tabs is the if statement combined with the row() function.

Why does cause the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you were making the `IF` condition to replace first value `BestelltabelleImport!I11` with the header. you could just go with the following:

```
={"Bestellte Gesamtmenge";transpose(arrayformula(BestelltabelleImport!I11:IS11))}
```